# Shared drive between two Linux virtual machines

Tags: virtual-machine, shared-disk

Assume I have two virtual machines.

- How do I share a VMDK drive between them?
- What solution do you recommend? Outside OS with NFS share?

Both of OSes see this drive as: `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: What hypervisor are you using?

Comment: Will the two machines use the disk at the same time? If not, how do you guarantee that it won't happen?